# Marionette JS 3: ui has string selector after second show view

Tags: view, coffeescript, marionette

The problem is that after the second `show view`. `this.ui.uielemnet` return not an element but only a string selector.  Events and other logic works well but i can`t get element after second`show vie`.  In the first`show view` everything works as planed.

code is below.  i add console log for explain.  CoffeeScript)

Router:

```
    class App.Routers.PanelRouter extends Marionette.AppRouter
      initialize: (options = {}) ->
        @mainView = options.cpView

      routes:
        'sbis-docs(/)': 'sbisDocShow'
        'sbis-send(/)': 'sbisSendShow'


      sbisDocShow: ->
        view = new App.Views.SbisDoc
        @mainView.getRegion('childRegion').show view
        view.showTable()

      sbisSendShow: ->
        view = new App.Views.SendSbis
        @mainView.getRegion('childRegion').show view

part of view

class App.Views.SendSbis extends Marionette.View

  template: _.template(App.Templates.SbisSend);

  initialize:() ->
    vent.on('event:change-search-method', @changeSearchMethod)
    vent.on('event:change-send-method', @changeSendMethod)

  changeSearchMethod: (data) =>
    if data.checked
      @ui.cust.attr('placeholder', 'Customer ID')
      @ui.labelCust.text('Номер договора')
    else
      @ui.cust.attr('placeholder', 'Логин')
      @ui.labelCust.text('Логин пользователя')


  changeSendMethod: (data) =>
    console.log @ui.month
    if data.checked
      @ui.month.prop('disabled', false)
    else
      @ui.month.prop('disabled', true)

  ui:
    sendDocs: '#send-docs'
    form:     '#form-docs'
    cust:     '#cust'
    year:     '#year'
    month:    '#month'
    labelCust:'#label-cust'
```

Other view:

```
class App.Views.SetupSend extends Marionette.View
  template: _.template(App.Templates.SetupSend)

  onAttach: ->
    @ui.checkboxes.bootstrapToggle()

  ui:
    search: '#search-method'
    send: '#send-method'
    checkboxes: 'input[type=checkbox][data-toggle^=toggle]'

  events:
    'change @ui.search': 'changeSearchMethod'
    'change @ui.send': 'changeSendMethod'

  changeSearchMethod: (e) ->
    vent.trigger('event:change-search-method', e.target)

  changeSendMethod: (e) ->
    vent.trigger('event:change-send-method', e.target)
```

In first time in  `changeSendMethod: (data)` console log is
`[input#month.form-control, prevObject: r.fn.init[1]]` 
But when i change route and comeback again console.log is 
`#month`

If i change `@ui.month.prop('disabled', false)` on `$(@ui.month).prop('disabled', false)` it will be work. But i don understand why it happens and how i can fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the problem was that after new `show view` append new     `vent.on('event:change-search-method', @changeSearchMethod)`

solve in my case

```
  onDestroy: () ->
    vent.off('event:change-search-method', @changeSearchMethod)
    vent.off('event:change-send-method', @changeSendMethod)
```